# Wowza Transcoded Stream not Playing in Chrome WebRTC

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, webrtc, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am encoding VP8 via WebRTC to Wowza Streaming Engine. I am then transcoding the stream to H264. The VP8 stream plays back in Google Chrome perfectly but the H264 stream won't play.

The H264 stream WILL play in Firefox. No other browsers though.

What could this be?

**Transcoded stream info:** 
H264 Baseline 3.0 
Bitrate: 350kbps

Answer (score 0):

Chrome requires H264 profile-level-id 42e01f (Constrained Baseline) and you are encoding 42001e (Baseline 3.0 max_bit_rate:10000).